# How do I convert a string that is in the format of list into an actual python list without using eval() and exec() in python

Tags: python

For example, `convert_to_list('[4,5,[6,7],[8,[9,10]],11]')` returns the actual list `[4, 5, [6, 7], [8, [9, 10]], 11]`

This problem has bothered me for days. The only challenge is that I can not use `eval()` or `exec()` function.

edit: You’re not allowed to import any non-standard Python libraries, or to use Python’s built-in eval() and
exec() function. You’re not allowed to use files. ( This is the instruction from my python course )

Comment: Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Comment: you need a stack (list using `append` and `pop`), start a new list every time you see a `[` and finish that list and return to the previous list on the stack when you see `]`. This is obviously a homework problem and you haven't done the bare minimum of even state what you've tried and why it didn't work. You've basically said "solve my problem for me" and that isn't what stackoverflow is for.

Comment: Hi, sorry this is my first time posting on stack overflow so I didn't know the ethics around here. My friend referred me here. To answer you I have tried that method but I was stuck at list inside a list. I could put the integers into a list but I find it hard to put a list into another list then put it into the bigger list.

Comment: @Barebear If you'd posted your code you'd have gotten more sympathy. You could post another question where you include the code you've written and what part you're confused about or having difficulty with and that might get better responses

Answer (score 3):

You can use json module

```
list1='[4,5,[6,7],[8,[9,10]],11]'

import json
json.loads(list1)
```

**output:**

```
[4, 5, [6, 7], [8, [9, 10]], 11]
```

Comment: Hi, your method certainly can work however I forgot to mention we can't import Python libraries. (sorry, this question is from my uni python course)

Comment: I'll update if I get an answer without using any imports.

Comment: You'll learn more if you try to do it yourself.  You need to write a lexer that breaks the input into tokens "[", "]", ",", and <number>, and you'll have to write parser that understands how the tokens fit together.